# Stack Overflow Question Tag Textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking to implement something similar to the Tags textbox on Stack Overflow.

Ideally, the tag suggestions will come directly from the database or else be loaded straight from the database and multiples can be selected. I'd like to be able to insert values to the database if they're not contained in the dataset.

Anyone have any good implementations of this that I can refer to?

Comment: Stackoverflow is a good example  :) I'm not sure to be honest. Does it need jquery/ajax type features?

Answer (score 2):

You can use JQuery Autocomplete plugin.

[Documentation of Autocomplete](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/autocomplete)

[Demo for Autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/)

Answer (score 2):

This plugin looks like it might do the job: http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/

*Disclaimer: I've never used it, and have made the above statement based on face value only.*